# Get the current element and the list containing everything else in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, list-comprehension

What is the fastest way to get the list containing pairs of the current element with the list containing every other element? This should be fast as the list could contain a million elements or more.

For example given the list `(1 2 3)`

I want to get the list `((1 (2 3)) (2 (1 3)) (3 (1 2)))`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work without traversing the entire vector over and over:

```
(defn this-and-that [xs]
  (map-indexed (fn [i x]
                [x (concat (take i xs) 
                           (drop (inc i) xs))])
              xs))
```

and also works for nils:

```
user=> (this-and-that [1 2 nil 3])
([1 (2 nil 3)] [2 (1 nil 3)] [nil (1 2 3)] [3 (1 2 nil)])
```

Answer (score 4):

"a million elements" is not a lot. Try if this is fast enough:

```
(defn this-and-that
  [s]
  (map-indexed (fn [i el]
                 [el (keep-indexed #(if (= %1 i)
                                            nil
                                            %2) s)]) s))
```

Example:

```
user> (this-and-that [1 2 3])
([1 (2 3)] [2 (1 3)] [3 (1 2)])
```

Note that this code doesn't work correctly for seqs containing `nil`.

Answer (score 4):

Other answers give good ways of doing this, however what you are describing is fundamentally an O(n^2) operation assuming that you actually realise all the lazy sequences etc. This probably isn't going to be a good idea if n >= 1,000,000

You might want to consider broadening the scope of the code you are considering to see if you can find a more efficient algorithm overall.

For example, you might find that is is better to convert the entire list into a vector, and writing your algorithm in terms of indexed access into a vector.

Answer (score 1):

How about using sets?

```
user> (let [xs #{1 2 3}]
        (for [x xs] [x (disj xs x)]))
([1 #{2 3}] [2 #{1 3}] [3 #{1 2}])
```

Doing this on a set with a million items isn't too bad time-wise:

```
(let [xs (set (range 1000000))]
  (time (count (for [x xs] [x (disj xs x)]))))
"Elapsed time: 841.668 msecs"
1000000
```